# How do I determine the actual size of a NetApp filer snapshot?

Tags: cifs, snapshot, netapp

We have a volume serving up CIFS data, which seems to have a lot more snapshot data than the rest. I suspect that this is due to a higher rate of change, and that I could determine this using the `snap delta` command. But I'd also like to be able to look at the snapshot sizes and target a particular one based on its size too.

In the CLI and System Manager, when viewing the snapshots repeatedly over the space of a few minutes, the size gradually increases up to a point and then drops right back down again. By this I don't mean that the snapshots are increasing and decreasing in size, just the reported size. Ideally, I'd like to know what causes this to happen.

More importantly, though, how would I determine the *actual* size of a snapshot?

Comment: You may also be able to find useful answers on the netapp filers admins mailing list at http://www.teaparty.net/mailman/listinfo/toasters (disclaimer: I run the list).

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite hard to say definitively because of how a snap works' A snapshot isn't any data in it's own right, it's just a copy of the inode table. Blocks referenced by this inode table have an increased reference count. Blocks are only freed when their reference count drops to zero.

This is - essentially - how deduplication works too. Pointers are redirected to the duplicate block, and it's reference count is increased. The 'old' block has its ref count decreased, and therefore it may become a candidate for releasing. (This will be after any snapshots that reference it have expired).

These 'freed up' blocks aren't actually reused immediately though - the way WAFL works is that an incoming write (usually!) goes to a new block entirely anyway, with 'free' blocks being cleared up as a background process.

This is why it's actually pretty hard to tell how large a snapshot is - because you essentially need to inspect each block within it, to see if that particular block is unique to that particular snap. `snap delta` and `snap list` are reasonably good approximations of this, but because of inter-snap dependencies a perfect answer is really hard to give.